# Show url link only if condition meet using data in model - Django

Tags: python, django

I am using template to render basic html in django and specify link as below.

```
<li><a href="{% url 'project:geometry' object.pk %}">Geometry</a></li>
```

I want to hide this link based on condition using model information.
Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Put that under an `{% if condition %}<your_html>{% endif %}` block?

Comment: Sometimes I have a hard time not screaming "READ THE F... MANUAL".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can surround the html in an [if statement](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/templates/builtins/#if) using the Django template language:

```
{% if object.something %}
    <li><a href="{% url 'project:geometry' object.pk %}">Geometry</a></li>  
{% endif %}
```

You can use [operators](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/templates/builtins/#boolean-operators), [filters](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/templates/builtins/#filters) or [complex expressions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/templates/builtins/#complex-expressions) if `object.something` is not a boolean

Answer (score 0):

Django has an `if` template tag, see:

> https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/templates/builtins/#if

from the docs:

```
{% if not athlete_list %}
  There are no athletes.
{% endif %}
```